# Apache camel without maven

Tags: java, maven-2, apache-camel

I have a hard time finding documentation/tutorials or just getting a dependency overview without going into some spiralling maven-nightmare.

I even have trouble getting the examples to work, as its an endless compile,run,search,repeat routine.  Can anyone recommend some information resources for someone not succombing to the maven-pressure ?:)

Answer (score 7):

> I have a hard time finding documentation/tutorials or just getting a dependency overview without going into some spiralling maven-nightmare.

Whatever your opinions on Maven are, the fact is that having some understanding of Maven would help you a lot, especially since many projects are using it and and even more especially in the particular case of Apache Camel which has a myriad of modules.

> I even have trouble getting the examples to work, as its an endless compile, run, search, repeat routine. Can anyone recommend some information resources for someone not succombing to the maven-pressure

The fun part is that this would be extremely easy with Maven but never mind. Go to the [maven generated website](http://camel.apache.org/maven/), look at the [Camel :: Examples](http://camel.apache.org/maven/examples/index.html) modules, click on any of the sample and check the *Dependencies* (under *Project Information*). And good luck with the  manual setup of the classpath because each project has a decent bunch of dependencies if you take the transitive one into account :)

**Update:** As pointed out in another answer, the samples actually come with an Ant `build.xml`. Or you could use [MOP](http://mop.fusesource.org/) to spit the class path for you or even directly run executable classes like this:

```
mop run org.apache.camel:camel-example-pojo-messaging org.apache.camel.spring.Main
```

Any of these options would be a lot easier than setting up the class path manually.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all examples have an ANT build.xml file as well, and there is a README.txt file telling you how to run the examples.

And if are not into learning how to Maven you could consider James Strachans newest tool called mop which is a command line launcher to run Java stuff. It can transparently download and use maven and its deps. So its just a matter of installing mop and using it to run the examples.

http://mop.fusesource.org/

Comment: Link is broken, site is down. I did find http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.mop/mop-core/1.0-m1

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downloading each missing resource, try to add repositories to your settings.xml that contain many of the resources you need.

[This tool](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/index.html) can help you locate repositories that have a given resource.

Specifically, the [JavaNet](http://download.java.net/maven/2/) repository has many of the previously "Restricted Sun" resources not available in the default global repository.

Comment: He doesn't want additional repositories, he wants to not use maven at all.

Comment: The alternative to my answer is to create your own ant script and download all the dependencies manually...  I gave him the simpler solution.  It accomplished his *goal* of compiling the project if not answers his question directly.  It's not what you want but what you need. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the Camel distribution archive, which includes all the camel jars and all the dependent libraries as well?

Comment: Its not a big problem getting hold of the jars, but for a small task I assume I don't need all 76 of them:)

Comment: @neheh: no, but now it sounds like you're trying to solve the problem maven was designed to solve without having to use maven.  Why not determine your camel requirements, make a POM with those requirements and then use the mvn dependency:tree command to determine what the full set of jars you need is.  Better yet, use ant in combination with Maven to create a tgz file with exactly those jars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to at least START with ant (and although I cannot guarantee it works) but try using:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ant-plugin/ant-mojo.html

This has an ant:ant task that will generate your build.xml from the maven project.
It's not perfect but will give you an easy way to feed your ant addiction.

Also, as Claus Ibsen already pointed out (and of course he should know ;)) there are already build.xmls for most of the examples.